# Finding out CPU activity between two timestamps under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cpu, benchmarking, cpu-usage

I'm interested in finding the total activity of the system between two instants in time. Under Linux, I can do this by reading `/proc/stat` twice. Under MacOS, I can call `host_statistics` twice. Under BSDs, I can also manage with a `sysctl`.

However, I have no idea how to do this under Windows. The closest equivalent I have found is `\Processor(*)\% Processor Time`, but this only gives me some kind of "current activity" (10ms-scale, if I understand correctly), rather than a total activity.

I am coding in regular (unmanaged) C++. My code needs to check the system use every ~10-15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it seems that `GetSystemTimes` will provide the data I need.